# How do I upgrade AMD PSP drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers

If I look at C:\Windows\system32\drivers\amdpsp.sys, it is version 4.15.0.0.  The latest version is 5.17.0.0.  I'd like to upgrade to the latest.

I tried Windows update but it says I am up to date.

I went to update catalog https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=AMD+PSP

Not exactly sure which one to download, but many seem to point to the same file

I get a CAB file.  Reading online, I rename it to a "KB" file but there is no KB number.  So I skip that step.  Then run "dism /online /add-package /packagepath:filename.cab"

When I run this, I get an error "An error occurred trying to open filename.cab Error: 0x80070002.
The system cannot find the file specified."

I try extracting the CAB file and its just drivers.  I try going to windows update and updating the driver pointing to that folder but it doesnt update anything.

I then goto AMD: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-ryzen-chipset-3-10-08-506
I run the installer, it specifically says it is installing the PSP driver 5.17.0.0.
However, after install and reboot, amdpsp.sys remains unchanged and at version 4.15.0.0